# How can one determine the committer of a cherry-pick in Git?

Tags: git, merge, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

In Git, `cherry-pick` retains the original commit's author, timestamp etc, at least when there are no conflicts. But is there any way to determine what user performed the cherry-pick which brought that commit to the new branch?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The author will be picked up from the original commit, but the committer (shown with `git log --format=full`) will be the one doing the cherry picking. This committer field is not secure, as cherry-pick commit creation is ultimately under the control of the cherry-picker. The only reliable way to track the commit creator, in this case the cherry pick instigator, is by signing off on the commit.

A simpler method is to carefully log pushes on the git server. The commits introduced by a push indicate who did the cherry-pick or, more precisely, who published it.

Answer (score 15):

Use either the `--pretty=full` argument to `git log` which results in something like:

```
git log -1 --pretty=full
commit 123abc
Author: Author Name
Commit: Commiter Name
Date: Wed Mar 20 09:43:20

Commmit Message
```

or, if you are only interested in the name of the commiter `--format="%cN"` which yields:

```
git log -1 --format="%cN"
Commiter Name
```

See [git-log(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) for more information.